# Router connected to my ethernet

Tags: wifi, audit, social-engineering, ethernet

I'm guessing that someone is bringing his router to provide wifi to his coworkers, by connecting it to a certain point on one of the 8 floors of my building, how can I know where is connected?

Comment: There are lots of ways. An inventory scan on your network can identify rogue equipment, depending on how your network is set up. An app on your phone can track the wifi signal to a general physical location.

Comment: Related question: [Can anyone tell if a wireless router is plugged into an Ethernet port?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41521/can-anyone-tell-if-a-wireless-router-is-plugged-into-an-ethernet-port-without-a)

Comment: Maybe this Serverfault question (and its answers) is helpful: [Is it possible to find the physical location of a wireless router based upon the broadcast signal?](http://serverfault.com/q/88946)

Answer (score 0):

This greatly depends on what hardware and security you have at your office.  Here are some suggestions (keep in mind that I mostly know Cisco).  Port Security on the switches to make sure that multiple MAC addresses are not assigned, do some searching for wireless signals, watch utilization on specific ports/MAC addresses to see the highest usage and then investigate.  To prevent, you can look into 802.1X, but that is a huge investment and requires a lot of in-house knowledge.